# How to Add unimplemented methods from Interfaces with Xtend

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, code-generation, xtend

Does anyone know, how to do the quickfix to add unimplemented methods from an Interface with Xtend code ?

Comment: Please clarify what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an `interface MyInterface` that declares a method `void aMethod()` and a `class ImplementingClass implements MyInterface` and you want to know the syntax to implement `aMethod()`.

Using Xtend's *ProposalProvider* in *Eclipse* provides either to implement the unimplemented methods or to make `ImplementingClass` abstract.

[image: Xtend's ProposalPRovider in Eclipse.]

Using the *Add unimplemented methods* proposal the overriding method will be automatically generated for you. `ImplementingClass` then looks like this:

```
class ImplementingClass implements MyInterface {

    override aMethod() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("TODO: auto-generated method stub")
    }

}
```

As you can see, Xtend has a special keyword `overrides` to define a method that override an other method. It is used instead of the regular `def` keyword to define methods.

Simply remove the `throw ...` expression and implement the moethod.